# 401 Unauthorized when calling webservice provided by DUET Enterprise on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services

I'm trying to get the delivered content of DUET Enterprise working. (DUET Enterprise in the Sharepoint-SAP integration product developed jointly by Microsoft and SAP)

Web services on both the SAP Service Consumption Layer ( SCL ) and Sharepoint sides are used to support this integration.

When trying to call the webservices on the Sharepoint side (both http and https), I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. I've tried calling the web service from SAP as well as an independent SOAP client, such as soapUI, but I get the same 401 Unauthorized response.
I am able to view the WSDL of the webservice in a browser if I provide the same user name and password which I use to actually call the service.

Can anyone tell me what (additional) authorization is required on Sharepoint or IIS to be able to consume the webservices provided by DUET?

Regards
user940356

Comment: Yeah, this is on topic, I am not sure why it was closed, DUET is directly related to SharePoint and SAP, in fact this is the kind of answer that I wanted to see.

Answer (score 2):

What authentication model are you using? Are the web service located on the same machine as SharePoint?

The reason I'm asking is that you cannot re-delegate credentials from the web server to another server if you use ordinary NTLM authentication, where on the other hand Kerberos authentication does support this scenario. Also this would only be a problem if the web service is located on another server than SharePoint ([double hop](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;329986)).

Comment: @Alex This thread was closed, incorrectly in my view, as being off topic. I thought my question was quite clear- What authorizations are required to call DUET webservices. This question relates directly to Sharepoint configuration.  @ Anders Thanks anyway for your response. Both Sharepoint, IIS and the webservices in question are all on the same server.